# How to use a Pololu 5v AVR ISP Programmer to program an AVR at 3.3v

Tags: uploading, voltage-level, isp

I have a [Pololu 5v AVR ISP](http://www.pololu.com/product/1300) which I have successfully used to program several Arduinos (a Mega, an Uno and a Pro Mini 5v). I now have a new Arduino compatible clone which is basically a clone of the pro mini 3.3V.

I am wondering if anyone else has used this programmer to program a 3.3V board without issues. I've seen a forum post on [pololu's forum](http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7368) which discusses modifications required - but I don't really understand what is necessary.

I've also found the software tool mentioned in the above forum post [here](http://www.pololu.com/docs/0J41) and I have downloaded it and built it.

When I run the aforementioned tool I get these options:

```
PgmCmd: Configuration and status utility for the Pololu USB AVR Programmer.
Version: 1.0.1.0
Options:
 -l, --list             list available devices
 -d, --device SERIALNUM (optional) select device with given serial number
 -s, --status           display complete device status
     --freq NUM         sets the ISP frequency (in units of kHz)
     --linea ID
       or --lineb ID    set serial control signal associated with line A or B.
                        Valid IDs are: none, cd, dsr, ri, dtr, rts.
                        Warning: dtr and rts are outputs: -f option is required
     --swminor HEXNUM   AVR ISP software version minor (in hex, e.g. A)
     --swmajor HEXNUM   AVR ISP software version major (in hex)
     --hw HEXNUM        AVR ISP software hardware version (in hex)
     --vddmin NUM       set minimum allowed target vdd (units of mV)
     --vddmaxrange NUM  set maximum allowed target vdd range (units of mV)
     --restoredefaults  restore factory settings
     --bootloader       put device in to bootloader (firmware upgrade) mode
```

I then ran the --status option with the serial number of my programmer and got this:

```
Serial number:                  00048632
Firmware version:               1.07
Settings:
  ISP Frequency:                200 kHz
  Line A Identity:              None
  Line B Identity:              None
  AVR ISP hardware version:     F
  AVR ISP software version:     2.A
  Target VDD allowed minimum:   4384 mV
  Target VDD allowed max range: 512 mV
Last programming:
  Error: None
  Measured Target VDD Minimum:  N/A
  Measured Target VDD Range:    N/A
SLO-scope:
  State:                        Off
  Line A output:                Off
  Line B output:                Off
```

From this I deduced that my programmer is currently set at between about 4.38V and 4.89V which I presume corresponds to the 5V approximate voltage of the normal Arduino chips.

Given that the utility program allows me to set both the target minimum V<sub>dd</sub> and the target V<sub>dd</sub> max range should I therefore set it to something like a minimum of 2704 with a max range of 512 which should put the signal voltages at up to ~3.2V.

Is that all I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: Instead of modifying your programmer to wok with 3v you can also consider buying a USBasp programmer that has a jumper to select between 5v/3v. The cost is less than $3 from ebay.

Comment: I tried the usbasp method. I bought a cheap one off ebay. When it arrived it didn't work until I gave it a firmware upgrade - fortunately I had the other programmer to do that with. Then having had it's firmware upgrade I tested it out on my arduino with mega2560 and my arduino bt with a 328p. I simply tried the blink sketch - on the bt it worked but not on the 2560. Turns out cheap chinese programmers don't always set the fuses correctly and I had to reload the arduino bootloader using my other programmer. I decided not to risk using the usbasp on my 3.3v things.

Comment: That is actually unfortunate to hear. I have a USBasp clone (Baite EvUSBasp specifically) and have had success with it for the most part, but I've not tried it at 3.3V.

Comment: fair enough. i guess it's just a pot luck thing on which manufacturers clone you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since AVR ISP is simply a modified form of SPI, the most universal way to handle this is to use a 3/1 level translator such as the [MAX3392E](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3253). Once you provide it with 5V on V<sub>CC</sub> and 3V3 on V<sub>L</sub> it will translate the MOSI, SCK, and nRESET signals to 3V3 and the MISO signal to 5V.

Comment: Thx. I now have 2 more questions - why does MISO stay at 5V? and I'm not sure I can easily get hold of the part you mention but I do have several of these: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/8745
Could I use the tx (bi directional despite name) lines of those instead?

Comment: I should probably add I come from a Software background rather than hardware and have only really used the serial and I2C interfaces of the Arduinos for communication so haven't come across SPI before.

Comment: "MISO" stands for "Master In, Slave Out". It's the signal going from the slave (the device) to the master (the programmer). That translator should work provided that 1) you have 4 bits total, and 2) you fix the 3V3 side as described in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for this - eventually though I went with @alexan_e's solution of purchasing a cheap programmer from ebay. I didn't realize they were quite so cheap.

Comment: I've come back to this solution because cheap ebay programmers are cheap rubbish.